# APPCRASH in w3wp.exe process and KERNELBASE.DLL module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, crash, w3wp, worker-process

I sometimes receive below sequence of errors in my ASP.NET MVC application. This cause application to stop working correctly.

Below I specify the errors in order of appearance in the event log (sorry they are in spanish):

**Event id: 1325 - Source: ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0**

```
Message: Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.

StackTrace:    en System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItemHelper(WaitCallback callBack, Object state, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean compressStack)
   en System.Threading.ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback callBack, Object state)
   en System.Threading.TimerQueue.QueueTimerCompletion(TimerQueueTimer timer)
   en System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
   en System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()
```

**Event id: 1026 - Source: .Net Runtime**

```
Aplicación: w3wp.exe
Versión de Framework: v4.0.30319
Descripción: el proceso terminó debido a una excepción no controlada.
Información de la excepción: System.OutOfMemoryException
   en System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItemHelper(System.Threading.WaitCallback, System.Object, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean)
   en System.Threading.ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(System.Threading.WaitCallback, System.Object)
   en System.Threading.TimerQueue.QueueTimerCompletion(System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer)
   en System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
   en System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()
```

**Event id: 1000 - Source: Application Error**

```
Nombre de la aplicación con errores: w3wp.exe, versión: 8.5.9600.16384, marca de tiempo: 0x52157ba0
Nombre del módulo con errores: KERNELBASE.dll, versión: 6.3.9600.18895, marca de tiempo: 0x5a4b125e
Código de excepción: 0xe0434352
Desplazamiento de errores: 0x00015608
Identificador del proceso con errores: 0x1b18
Hora de inicio de la aplicación con errores: 0x01d6b2b0cdd1844c
Ruta de acceso de la aplicación con errores: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Ruta de acceso del módulo con errores: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Identificador del informe: f0eb8634-200a-11eb-80f2-000c290e0c8e
Nombre completo del paquete con errores: 
Identificador de aplicación relativa del paquete con errores:
```

**Event id: 1001 - Source Windows Error Reporting**

```
Depósito con errores , tipo 0
Nombre de evento: APPCRASH
Respuesta: No disponible
Identificador de archivo CAB: 0

Firma del problema:
P1: w3wp.exe
P2: 8.5.9600.16384
P3: 52157ba0
P4: KERNELBASE.dll
P5: 6.3.9600.18895
P6: 5a4b125e
P7: e0434352
P8: 00015608
P9: 
P10: 

Archivos adjuntos:

Es posible que estos archivos estén disponibles aquí:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_w3wp.exe_acdfde49977dc91b656d5d49242358776cd5a9_234314c6_22347083

Símbolo de análisis: 
Nueva búsqueda de una solución: 0
Identificador de informe: f0eb8634-200a-11eb-80f2-000c290e0c8e
Estado del informe: 4100
Depósito con algoritmo hash:
```

**Event id: 5011 - Source: WAS**

```
Un proceso que sirve al grupo de aplicaciones 'AppPool Name' ha sufrido un error de comunicación grave con el servicio WAS (Windows Process Activation Service). El Id. del proceso era '6936'. El campo de datos contiene el número de error.
```

Finally, the content of:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_w3wp.exe_acdfde49977dc91b656d5d49242358776cd5a9_234314c6_22347083

... is the following:

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=132491252939754815
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=f0eb8635-200a-11eb-80f2-000c290e0c8e
IntegratorReportIdentifier=f0eb8634-200a-11eb-80f2-000c290e0c8e
WOW64=1
NsAppName=w3wp.exe
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Nombre de la aplicación
Sig[0].Value=w3wp.exe
Sig[1].Name=Versión de la aplicación
Sig[1].Value=8.5.9600.16384
Sig[2].Name=Marca de tiempo de la aplicación
Sig[2].Value=52157ba0
Sig[3].Name=Nombre del módulo con errores
Sig[3].Value=KERNELBASE.dll
Sig[4].Name=Versión del módulo con errores
Sig[4].Value=6.3.9600.18895
Sig[5].Name=Marca de tiempo del módulo con errores
Sig[5].Value=5a4b125e
Sig[6].Name=Código de excepción
Sig[6].Value=e0434352
Sig[7].Name=Desplazamiento de excepción
Sig[7].Value=00015608
DynamicSig[1].Name=Versión del sistema operativo
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
DynamicSig[2].Name=Id. de configuración regional
DynamicSig[2].Value=3082
DynamicSig[22].Name=Información adicional 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=7f27
DynamicSig[23].Name=Información adicional 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=7f271d790c7c145821f2bb11b0882afd
DynamicSig[24].Name=Información adicional 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=3642
DynamicSig[25].Name=Información adicional 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=36421e5df16442010de98f7265517b06
UI[2]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\inetsrv\iisutil.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\pcwum.DLL
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\user32.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\inetsrv\w3wphost.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\inetsrv\nativerd.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\XmlLite.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ktmw32.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\inetsrv\IISRES.DLL
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mscoree.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\iiscore.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\inetsrv\W3TP.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\inetsrv\w3dt.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\HTTPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachuri.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachfile.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachtokn.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachhttp.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\compstat.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\defdoc.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\dirlist.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\protsup.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\redirect.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\static.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authanon.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authbas.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authsspi.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wkscli.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\netutils.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authmd5.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iprestr.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\diprestr.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\modrqflt.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\custerr.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\loghttp.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\isapi.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\filter.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\validcfg.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\compdyn.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iiswsock.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\websocket.dll
LoadedModule[83]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisetw.dll
LoadedModule[84]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisfreb.dll
LoadedModule[85]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisreqs.dll
LoadedModule[86]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iis_ssi.dll
LoadedModule[87]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\wbhst_pm.dll
LoadedModule[89]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\webengine.dll
LoadedModule[90]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\30bf1921503412fa2b0b70c448bd4ab8\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[91]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\3c3125abff791d75454612d56a7da162\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[92]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\1d432538b7e0e3d52913aa4f5b36e8d8\System.Core.ni.dll
LoadedModule[93]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web\f77e89489206885afc128f70c19efc78\System.Web.ni.dll
LoadedModule[94]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sxs.dll
LoadedModule[95]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web.8dc504e4#\990cd8eb6d85e791b5f3e843a9d90e95\System.Web.ApplicationServices.ni.dll
LoadedModule[96]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\847a79a9de247bda0ecaec386216714a\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[97]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\e585a2ad1fab2b202e0c6b289546f0ed\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[98]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\shell32.dll
LoadedModule[99]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data\7593fdde4731c8477e6fd44e5dbd3d83\System.Data.ni.dll
LoadedModule[100]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Ente96d83b35#\6a979220a04041f77f7086e65f1a83ef\System.EnterpriseServices.ni.dll
LoadedModule[101]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\0d42a1409a817202866fc5eea824553f\System.Drawing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[102]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Comp46f2b404#\1e9eec3b30c9bc0a918d4679cba15c1b\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ni.dll
LoadedModule[103]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Dire5d62f0a2#\91e46a16d82d0a58cd932786c2b49c65\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ni.dll
LoadedModule[104]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Dired13b18a9#\d9cdc87c97d1ba6860d7e31df676402f\System.DirectoryServices.ni.dll
LoadedModule[105]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.B83e9cb53#\bed19a3163bc9d0b00dd8fccb051231e\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.ni.dll
LoadedModule[106]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.B3325a29b#\5ff0b599ef87bb285f257102ceb2161d\Microsoft.Build.Framework.ni.dll
LoadedModule[107]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runt19c51595#\93cfd2500f59e970249f195ed1d35014\System.Runtime.Caching.ni.dll
LoadedModule[108]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web.82d5542b#\08d5b9aa16fb531c7fe05aa37c3504fd\System.Web.RegularExpressions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[109]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Design\91849517df17dc8819c08d6dc36cf6b9\System.Design.ni.dll
LoadedModule[110]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Security\8eb1121bf9ab68a5439d5fabd231a164\System.Security.ni.dll
LoadedModule[111]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Serv759bfb78#\a01c916d9f05e50f03658357cc1a35cf\System.ServiceProcess.ni.dll
LoadedModule[112]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web.Services\814efbf4e74890f1d9050bb6f68a45aa\System.Web.Services.ni.dll
LoadedModule[113]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.Baa2ca56b#\eae8575fb41f8531c6dc763daf8fd26c\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.ni.dll
LoadedModule[114]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\2aecc88f903f5cb542f253d4ad399a79\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
LoadedModule[115]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data.SqlXml\f6e1f478ab40b555003191efc8348d3c\System.Data.SqlXml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[116]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Numerics\81379ac9d805c96bcd8c76367e26d825\System.Numerics.ni.dll
LoadedModule[117]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Transactions\f11ec1d1dbda3098a9d5832138e5e4cc\System.Transactions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[118]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runt73a1fc9d#\26a395a22d8777e88c8efb28ecb302f5\System.Runtime.Remoting.ni.dll
LoadedModule[119]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xaml\544a85595dd947e24c7ed9f7b7fb3892\System.Xaml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[120]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Draw0a54d252#\629d45c022337290d73cb2fbafbee2d8\System.Drawing.Design.ni.dll
LoadedModule[121]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Accessibility\b3c2efc049cd84286389be496aefe2cc\Accessibility.ni.dll
LoadedModule[122]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data86569bbf#\3112229c09f95d10b1149c03f4a30b32\System.Data.OracleClient.ni.dll
LoadedModule[123]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runt9064068c#\4a5e2eab988bbd46a32e12da3b980a50\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.ni.dll
LoadedModule[124]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Confe64a9051#\ca52193474f92fe354c5a838c3634ff9\System.Configuration.Install.ni.dll
LoadedModule[125]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Deployment\43fcea8840fc393c4bceb34c5f3d4e74\System.Deployment.ni.dll
LoadedModule[126]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runteb92aa12#\13c2fc9793b91e8561bb5268bd0c5b86\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll
LoadedModule[127]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\SMDiagnostics\c7c9a91ce7ff891dd3949fc8c36636af\SMDiagnostics.ni.dll
LoadedModule[128]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Servd1dec626#\3199c8664f21bd7f86148da9f9b0b13f\System.ServiceModel.Internals.ni.dll
LoadedModule[129]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.JScript\a706fa80d93451e41378913325117b1b\Microsoft.JScript.ni.dll
LoadedModule[130]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web.b3fa0d97#\836d7afee740fe462f19d39bfd28d8be\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.ni.dll
LoadedModule[131]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.Wccf05646#\26116bb4846e6b6fe4c6f0fa587a9ca7\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.ni.dll
LoadedModule[132]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
LoadedModule[133]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Compba577418#\611b66baf7589cfb10276b676399243f\System.ComponentModel.Composition.ni.dll
LoadedModule[134]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web.28b9ef5a#\01bdedd03119487c3da12fe441587aa5\System.Web.Extensions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[135]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.ServiceModel\1c9e89158f1f6034b83cd6a6f3bc171d\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
LoadedModule[136]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data.Linq\e52863740d94c0c95c7289884842b1bc\System.Data.Linq.ni.dll
LoadedModule[137]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Serv14b62006#\88b1ee2f93329359fcb54b105b2a4c8d\System.ServiceModel.Activation.ni.dll
LoadedModule[138]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data16016462#\9e19ffc066e52bc34cc804295a64e2c2\System.Data.Services.Design.ni.dll
LoadedModule[139]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data14bed3a9#\5c1e55d110a2e89dda58da3af0411ab7\System.Data.Services.Client.ni.dll
LoadedModule[140]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data.Entity\9963e28483dfb54af19e3d44b88f4f94\System.Data.Entity.ni.dll
LoadedModule[141]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.IdentityModel\656b4879b5ebb4177fd6022d3088a95f\System.IdentityModel.ni.dll
LoadedModule[142]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.Te49ad7d9#\4201b02e832555b53354f00fd030577d\Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.ni.dll
LoadedModule[143]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Messaging\52407cde925930346d56d61b7409b496\System.Messaging.ni.dll
LoadedModule[144]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Net.Http\51b8201c6feff300fad5c33a188095ef\System.Net.Http.ni.dll
LoadedModule[145]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runt93d54979#\cd3892f80bfbee5dc207e4722e394f44\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[146]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Idena7b556ff#\848fa1b4bbb9c52cf6d7c2eb8de6a14a\System.IdentityModel.Selectors.ni.dll
LoadedModule[147]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml.Linq\cafa4daf6b737bccfdeaed59a0e8dc81\System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll
LoadedModule[148]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xaml.Hosting\cbb87f96e79215a7ec4d1b6146e03d0d\System.Xaml.Hosting.ni.dll
LoadedModule[149]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Serv14259fd9#\161a24644ab45d141a9efa94f84f7821\System.ServiceModel.Activities.ni.dll
LoadedModule[150]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Activities\319c8978e489e30d011eb8b76e92bac0\System.Activities.ni.dll
LoadedModule[151]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Acti2661942e#\bb2e5dbdbcc5b67ba6c9e5413515c51a\System.Activities.DurableInstancing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[152]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.Vf4833439#\4c22b9245ae3b8d0b0b1c5c2a6eb3f73\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler.ni.dll
LoadedModule[153]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.V9921e851#\b84427e7e2cc9bf667bd6276f5e1d8de\Microsoft.VisualBasic.ni.dll
LoadedModule[154]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Management\865aa9644e31c6e25dac649a19deb2fc\System.Management.ni.dll
LoadedModule[155]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.CSharp\1a402765ba32d31a6aa8f2d96e6f0657\Microsoft.CSharp.ni.dll
LoadedModule[156]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Dynamic\37979e6f474d567379d7b747c7b85e0d\System.Dynamic.ni.dll
LoadedModule[157]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
LoadedModule[158]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[159]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[160]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Servf73e6522#\62ae2d2c39298b334d5ea0eb45c3f202\System.ServiceModel.Web.ni.dll
LoadedModule[161]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Serv30e99c02#\cb9aa80f6ebc75f8632176133e36db82\System.ServiceModel.Channels.ni.dll
LoadedModule[162]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Workd8194f73#\e7f1cc39ea4c5fa98d8278cd704aa08e\System.WorkflowServices.ni.dll
LoadedModule[163]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Work0493292f#\c477237de85af409f451a39bdb38cc8d\System.Workflow.Runtime.ni.dll
LoadedModule[164]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Workca489553#\bd9ffa963fd482637aa211dc21a826be\System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ni.dll
LoadedModule[165]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Workfffcbcd8#\20007137b0f66bc0e344db41fa3b1398\System.Workflow.Activities.ni.dll
LoadedModule[166]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.W71daf281#\20e71e44bbab93d380f5fd26736f34d2\Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.ni.exe
LoadedModule[167]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data7706cdc8#\b412ae4d5af5447ac12343afdc26509c\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[168]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web.2486c0f5#\c76d5f40f4b587f48d73a1ce487a0070\System.Web.DynamicData.ni.dll
LoadedModule[169]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web.Entity\d9739716d0325f5d228f922bbf559ff4\System.Web.Entity.ni.dll
LoadedModule[170]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll
LoadedModule[171]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msv1_0.DLL
LoadedModule[172]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cryptdll.dll
LoadedModule[173]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
LoadedModule[174]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web.8da3333a#\d3fb1c90afd109e2c384a987c05e1fda\System.Web.DataVisualization.ni.dll
LoadedModule[175]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Ente96d83b35#\6a979220a04041f77f7086e65f1a83ef\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
LoadedModule[176]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
LoadedModule[177]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler.dll
LoadedModule[178]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP120_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[179]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\fcf2f41273e658ac8a1112abf10741ba\WindowsBase.ni.dll
LoadedModule[180]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web.Mobile\f9ef4fd9a751edba1245a38ff07a064a\System.Web.Mobile.ni.dll
LoadedModule[181]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll
LoadedModule[182]=C:\Windows\system32\security.dll
LoadedModule[183]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SECUR32.DLL
LoadedModule[184]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\schannel.dll
LoadedModule[185]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Kerberos.DLL
LoadedModule[186]=C:\Windows\system32\ntdsapi.dll
LoadedModule[187]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DSPARSE.DLL
LoadedModule[188]=C:\Windows\system32\netapi32.dll
LoadedModule[189]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\srvcli.dll
LoadedModule[190]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\LOGONCLI.DLL
LoadedModule[191]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
LoadedModule[192]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll
LoadedModule[193]=C:\Windows\system32\ncryptsslp.dll
LoadedModule[194]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\rasapi32.dll
LoadedModule[195]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\rasman.dll
LoadedModule[196]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\rtutils.dll
LoadedModule[197]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\winhttp.dll
LoadedModule[198]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
LoadedModule[199]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
LoadedModule[200]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrcompression.dll
LoadedModule[201]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\odbc32.dll
LoadedModule[202]=C:\SAP\DataAccess\ODBC\dll\sybdrvodb.dll
LoadedModule[203]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9600.17810_none_7c5b6194aa0716f1\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[204]=C:\SAP\DataAccess\ODBC\dll\MSVCP110.dll
LoadedModule[205]=C:\SAP\DataAccess\ODBC\dll\MSVCR110.dll
LoadedModule[206]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MTXDM.DLL
LoadedModule[207]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\comsvcs.dll
LoadedModule[208]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\AUTHZ.dll
LoadedModule[209]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\gpapi.dll
LoadedModule[210]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.VisualC\0ec5b35dedd4ab36fe04458dc54b95fa\Microsoft.VisualC.ni.dll
LoadedModule[211]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[212]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\usp10.dll
LoadedModule[213]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.18790_none_dae0e7de5bc4763c\gdiplus.dll
LoadedModule[214]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DWrite.dll
LoadedModule[215]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
LoadedModule[216]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\T2Embed.DLL
LoadedModule[217]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\FontSub.DLL
LoadedModule[218]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\activeds.dll
LoadedModule[219]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\adsldpc.dll
LoadedModule[220]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WLDAP32.dll
LoadedModule[221]=C:\Windows\system32\adsldp.dll
LoadedModule[222]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mpr.dll
LoadedModule[223]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cscapi.dll
LoadedModule[224]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
LoadedModule[225]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINTRUST.dll
LoadedModule[226]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorsecimpl.dll
LoadedModule[227]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\imagehlp.dll
LoadedModule[228]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cryptnet.dll
LoadedModule[229]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.IO.Cf61e09c5#\20e16d7a8b0646613fd0b4b718addb6a\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.ni.dll
LoadedModule[230]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.IO.Cb3b124c8#\55cff7cc18cefc3a997b671f1c9aee98\System.IO.Compression.ni.dll
LoadedModule[231]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll
LoadedModule[232]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSDART.DLL
LoadedModule[233]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ole db\vfpoledb.dll
LoadedModule[234]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
LoadedModule[235]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\comdlg32.dll
LoadedModule[236]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
LoadedModule[237]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[238]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
LoadedModule[239]=C:\Windows\System32\drprov.dll
LoadedModule[240]=C:\Windows\System32\WINSTA.dll
LoadedModule[241]=C:\Windows\System32\ntlanman.dll
LoadedModule[242]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\odbccp32.dll
FriendlyEventName=Dejó de funcionar
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=IIS Worker Process
AppPath=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=167391AF18062487C22442480A45B443
```

How can I detect the main cause of it? I do not know to interpret these kind of logs. Any help will be highly apreciated.

Comment: They can be related to each other, or simply irrelevant. But some does indicate serious out-of-memory issue there, which is likely to be caused by bad web apps. There is no simple fix, as every web apps are unique. If you cannot follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/troubleshoot-outofmemoryexception yourself, hire a consultant or open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: @LexLi Great article! thanks. Now I understand why OutOfMemory is often being thrown and consequently the application crashes when it has a high load.